# Javascript if statement with multiple elseifs

Tags: javascript, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have the below if statement in use to compare 2 rows in the same column in a table. I use the same block of code multiple times to perform the same calculation on different columns.

Basically, I want to have an arrow show both the movement in value between one row and the next, as well as the threshold the value falls into. So, for example, in my code below anything above 15 should be a red arrow and if the previous value was lower then the arrow should point up. I render the arrows using images called from another location later in my code, so the if statement just gives me the string for the appropriate arrow.

As I said above, I have the same block of code numerous times. The strange thing is, the output works for some variables and does't for others; even though it's the exact same code with the variable names replaced! It gives me the wrong are SOMETIMES for no apparent reason.

Do I have too many conditions? Is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Karl

```
var Arrow = " ";
if(KPI[0] > KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
{
    Arrow = "redarrowup.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] < KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
{
    Arrow = "redarrowdown.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] = KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
{
    Arrow = "redarrowflat.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] > KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 10 && KPI[0] < 15)
{
    Arrow = "yellowarrowup.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] < KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 10 && KPI[0] < 15)
{
    Arrow = "yellowarrowdown.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] = KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 10 && KPI[0] < 15)
{
    Arrow = "yellowarrowflat.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] > KPI[1] && KPI[0] < 10)
{   
    Arrow = "greenarrowup.png";
}
else if(KPI[0] < KPI[1] && KPI[0] < 10)
{   
    Arrow = "greenarrowdown.png";
}
else
{
    Arrow = "greenarrowflat.png";
}
```

Comment: When you say 'KPI[0] = KPI[1]' do you really mean 'KPI[0] == KPI[1]' or even ''KPI[0] === KPI[1]'?

Comment: You could try nesting ones with similar parameters. It wouldn't necessarily be more efficient, but it could make it easier to read/figure out flow.

Comment: Many made the same recommendation to replace "=" with "==" which solved my problem so thank you all! To all who offered up more efficient, neater, cleaner solutions thank you also; I will strive to utilise these solutions for future projects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I'd say that you have an "=" where you need an "==" (or even "===").  For example

```
if(KPI[0] = KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
```

should probably be

```
if(KPI[0] == KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
```

(or even === as I said).  And so forth.  "=" is an assignment operator, it sets the value of KPI[0] to the value of KPI[1] and then returns that value, so you are essentially doing the following:

```
KPI[0] = KPI[1];
if(KPI[1] && KPI[0] >= 15)
```

which I doubt is the intention.  That said, as several others have already said there are better ways to structure the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response Adam. The = conditions appear to work fine for me, it's the greater than or less than conditions that give me strange results; although I will add == as best practice going forward :)

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understood.  = is not a conditional operator at all, it's an assignment operator.  That means that in the first KPI[0] = KPI[1] you are changing the value of KPI[0] (to the value of KPI[1]).  This will of course then affect any later comparisions to KP[0] (including greater/less than), since the value of KP[0] you are comparing is not what you think it is.  It's not a question of best practice (== vs === as default can be considered such a discussion), it's a question of fundamentally different operations.

Comment: Wow, it was as simple as that! Thank you so much, problem solved :)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend expressing the different concepts separately and then combining them at the end. Like this:

```
var arrow;
var movement = "flat";
var band = "green";

if (KPI[0] > KPI[1]) {
    movement = "up";
} else if (KPI[0] < KPI[1]) {
    movement = "down";
}

if (KPI[0] >= 15) {
    band = "red";
} else if (KPI[0] >= 10) {
    band = "yellow";
}

arrow = band + "arrow" + movement + ".png";
```

You could also defer each of these elements to a function, so your final line would read:

```
arrow = getBand(KPI[0], KPI[1]) + "arrow" + getMovement(KPI[0], KPI[1]) + ".png";
```

This would make it easier to change the bands in isolation of this other logic.

Comment: I really like this idea... but will I need 3 variables for arrow, movement and band per variable I want to compare? I.e KPIarrow, KPImovement, KPIband, OTHERVARarraow, OTHERVARmovement, OTHERVARband, etc.?

Comment: Not fair :) I suggested a similar solution one minute earlier!

Comment: @Shedal - well done for a correct answer and +1 for your comment. Reduction on one extra else statement and using functions to make the code more cohesive may have got me the votes.

Comment: @KarlMajor - either variables, or defer those components off to a function. I can supply an example that uses functions to compose the arrow if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

```
function direction(val1, val2){
  return val1 < val2 ? "down" : val1 == val2 ? "flat" : "up";
}

function color(val){
  return val >= 15 ? "red" : val >= 10 ? "yellow" : "green";
}

var arrow = color(KPI[0]) +"arrow"+ direction(KPI[0], KPI[1]) +".png";
```

I always tell people not to copy and paste code if you don't understand it. You might be unfamiliar with the `?:` bit. It is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) (inline if).

If you need multiple arrows I would suggest to add a function for generating an arrow too:

```
function arrow(val1, val2){
  return color(val1) +"arrow"+ direction(val1, val2) +".png";
}

var kpiArrow = arrow(KPI[0], KPI[1]);
```

Comment: Unbeatable. Brilliant! Easily the best answer. Shortest, clearest by a country mile.

Comment: I like how short this is :) let me give it a try and report back! Thanks Jasper!

Comment: I like ternary statements, but not when they are nested. The aim should be for the greatest readability rather than the least lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in the number of if's. But you can structure your code better:

```
var direction, color;

// set direction

if(KPI[0] > KPI[1])
{
  direction = "up";
}
else if(KPI[0] < KPI[1])
{
  direction = "down";
}
else if(KPI[0] == KPI[1]) // there was an error in this condition, by the way
{
  direction = "flat";
}

// set color

if(KPI[0] >= 15)
{
  color = "red";
}
else if(KPI[0] >= 10 && KPI[0] < 15)
{
  color = "yellow";
}
else if(KPI[0] < 10)
{
  color = "green";
}

var Arrow = color + "arrow" + direction + ".png";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var arrow = "";

if (KPI[0] >= 15) {
   arrow = "redarrow";
}
else if (KPI[0] >= 10) {
   arrow = "yellowarrow";
}
else if (KPI[0] < 10) {
   arrow = "greenarrow";
}

if (KPI[0] < KPI[1]) {
   arrow += "down.png";
}
else if (KPI[0] > KPI[1]) {
   arrow += "up.png";
}
else if (KPI[0] == KPI[1]) {
   arrow += "flat.png";
}
```